# Text Wrap inside a rectangle created by HTML5 graphics

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a HTML5 project. I have created a rectangle using ctx.strokeRect(x,y,width,height). Also also filling text using ctx.fillText(textValue,x,y).But text floating outside the boundary. i want to keep all the text within the rectangle boundary using javascript as happen in TextArea (i.e. when we resize textarea then text wraps inside boundary)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134586/how-can-you-find-the-height-of-text-on-an-html-canvas and for wrapping http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936112/text-wrap-in-a-canvas-element

Comment: but these answers are not exactly wrap the text. In Ist ctx.mozDrawText('gM'); // This seems like tall text...  Doesn't it? giving an error.

Comment: @Shanky did you get to wrap the text within the rect boundaries? I'm facing a similar problem