# How to do rich typesetting for text in canvas element?

Tags: javascript, ios, canvas, word-wrap, typography

I'm looking for a way to draw multi-line text on a canvas element directly without using HTML/DOM. Best case scenario would be to find a JavaScript library, but my Googling attempts didn't come up with anything.

Ideally it would have the following functionality:

- Ability to set paragraph styles: First-line indent, line spacing, etc.
- Fast and robust implementation of text-wrapping algorithms with alignment/justification options
- Rich text formatting via some simplified subset of HTML or Markdown etc.

I'm hoping to find a solution that's a bit more advanced than [this tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-wrap-text-tutorial/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936112/text-wrap-in-a-canvas-element) which just deal with basic word/line wrapping.

Does anyone know of any possible solution? It may seem like it's a crazy thing to do, but think I have a fairly good justification! I'm evaluating [Ejecta](http://impactjs.com/ejecta) as a possible iOS environment to make a cross-platform game that has a reliance on text with beautiful typography, so HTML and DOM isn't available. ([We](http://www.inklestudios.com) make primarily text-based games)

Comment: This: https://github.com/bramstein/typeset contains a good line breaking algorithm including various text alignment options, a hyphenator, and makes use of canvas's `measureText` function, although outputs as `span`s. Could be made use of though, in combination with a basic line renderer.

Comment: We support multiline text rendering in [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com) as well as font family, text-alignment, text-decoration, text stroke, etc. There's no automatic wrapping built-in but you should be able to extend `fabric.Text` class and work from there.

Comment: Thanks @kangax, looks pretty powerful!

Answer (score 1):

As @kangax already pointed: `fabric.js` support multiline text rendering well as font family, text-alignment, text-decoration, text stroke, etc. There's no automatic wrapping built-in but you should be able to extend `fabric.Text` class and work from there.
Go to http://fabricjs.com/ for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Canvas has minimal text support as you have discovered.

To get rich-text capabilities, look at the source code for TinyMCE.

TinyMCE is an open-source, widely used javascript based text editor that is under active development.  It has excellent features and it's wide use and active development make for largely debugged and feature rich code.

You can start with this framework and pull the pieces that you need for use in canvas.

The project is available here:  https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce

Comment: Doesn't look like it uses canvas, and therefore doesn't require any special code to implement text wrapping/formatting etc? Seems to use an embedded iframe...