# HTML5 Canvas multi-line textboxes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Okay, so, essentially, I'm getting user input from an `<input>` tag and shoving it into a canvas. This is all well and good for one line, but there are some cases where I need whole paragraphs of text. As we are all aware, not every letter is of the same width, which means I can't have multiple `<input>` tags with a maxlength attribute. It's also jarring to have multiple input tags. Long story short: Is there any way to put PARAGRAPH textboxes into a HTML5 canvas element?

Comment: Check out : http://www.travisberry.com/2011/05/write-text-anywhere-with-html5-canvas/ to get the idea. I think if you customise it to an extend, it will serve your purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text wrap in a <canvas> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936112/text-wrap-in-a-canvas-element)

Comment: Why you don't use [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) for multiline input?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you go ahead and use a textarea to get multiline handling?

```
<textarea name="myTextArea" cols="30" rows="5" />
```

Comment: The issue I assume is translating it to canvas.

Comment: Yes, the issue is translating to canvas. Also, it doesn't matter if the input tag itself can't linebreak, the issue is that fillText() only support a single line, and not, say, a paragraph.

Comment: You can use a custom solution for that, [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7974313/1477051)