# Retrieve lines of text stored in an array and display them on a canvas with line breaks?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Below is an array with its elements that store some long lines of text.

```
var fcontent = [
["Definition: The term computer is obtained from the word compute. A computer is an electronic device that inputs (takes in) facts (known as data), and then processes (does something to or with) it. Afterwards it outputs, or displays, the results for you to see. Data is all kinds of facts, including, pictures, letters, numbers, sounds, etc."],

["Moreover: A computer is a system that is made up of a number of components. Next is a diagram of a computer system with some of its components"],
];
```

I am using the following function to display the elements on Canvas,:

```
firstLevelContent:function()
{
    var startPoint = 48;  $('.gamelayer').hide();
    $('#gamecanvas').show();       
    for (var i=0; i<fcontent.length; i++)
    {
        game.context.strokeRect(1,  25, 637, 385);
        game.context.fillStyle = 'brown';
        game.context.font = 'bold 20px sans-serif';
        game.context.textBaseline = 'bottom';
        game.context.fillText(fcontent[i], 2, startPoint);
        startPoint+=17;
    }
},
```

But the text is displayed as it is in the code, I want find a way of break the lines to fit the width (640) of the canvas, so that I can see all the text displayed. pls help me. Thanks.

Comment: this is not a javascript issue. All you need to do is to specify a width for your canvas in css. Can u please show me the css you use for your canvas? if there are the right css classes, the text will automaticaly fit his width.

Comment: @GeorgianBurungiu. No, html canvas does not automatically apply line breaks to fit text to the canvas width.

Comment: You must do the text wrapping manually with javascript.  You can use the context.measureText method to get the width of each word.  When the accumulated words exceed the canvas length, begin a new line.  Check out this previous Stackoverflow answer on how to wrap text to multiple lines on html canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936112/text-wrap-in-a-canvas-element

Answer (score 0):

You need a word wrap function that will separate your text into suitable-length lines. There are other suggestions on SO about how to do this, but it seems like most of them don't properly account for overly-long words (i.e. when an individual word is longer than the required width) or whitespace (i.e. most assume a single space character between words). I had a think and came up with this:

```
function wordWrap(text, width, ctx, useHyphen) {
    var words = text.split(/\b(?=\w)/),
        wrappedText = [],
        wordLength = 0,
        fullLength = 0,
        line = "",
        lineLength = 0,
        spacer = useHyphen ? "-" : "",
        spacerLength = ctx.measureText(spacer).width,
        letterLength = 0;

    // make sure width to font size ratio is reasonable
    if (ctx.measureText("M"+spacer).width > width) {return [];}

    // produce lines of text
    for (var i=0, l=words.length; i<l; i++) {

        wordLength = ctx.measureText(words[i].replace(/\s+$/,"")).width;
        fullLength = ctx.measureText(words[i]).width;

        if (lineLength + wordLength < width) {
            line += words[i];
            lineLength += fullLength;
        } else if (wordLength < width) {
            wrappedText.push(line);
            line = words[i];
            lineLength = fullLength;  
        } else {
            // word is too long so needs splitting up

            for (var k=0, lim=words[i].length; k<lim; k++) {

                letterLength = ctx.measureText(words[i][k]).width;

                if (words[i][k+1] && /\S/.test(words[i][k+1])) {

                    if (lineLength + letterLength + spacerLength < width) {
                        line += words[i][k];
                        lineLength += letterLength;
                    } else {
                        if (true || words[i][k+1] && /\s/.test(words[i][k+1])) {line += spacer;}
                        wrappedText.push(line);
                        line = words[i][k];
                        lineLength = letterLength;
                    }

                } else {
                    // last 'letter' in word

                    if (lineLength + letterLength < width) {
                        line += words[i].substr(k);
                        lineLength += ctx.measureText(words[i].substr(k)).width;
                    } else {
                        line += spacer;
                        wrappedText.push(line);
                        line = words[i].substr(k);
                        lineLength = ctx.measureText(words[i].substr(k)).width;
                    }

                    break;

                }


            }

        }
    }

    wrappedText.push(line);

    // strip trailing whitespace from each line
    for (var j=0, len=wrappedText.length; j<len; j++) {
        wrappedText[j] = wrappedText[j].replace(/\s+$/,"");
    }

    return wrappedText;

}
```

It can probably be improved upon, but it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/cP5Fz/9/

Note: You'll need to set the font size that you'll be using **before** calling the `wordWrap` function.

As for the arguments you pass:

- `text`: the text you want wrapping
- `width`: the width that the text must fit into
- `ctx`: the context of the canvas
- `useHyphen`: set to `true` if you want long words to be broken up using a hyphen (optional)

It'll then return an array of strings that will each individually fit into the required space.

Comment: Words are hyphenated at syllable breaks so you could improve your hyphenation a bit by breaking after the first consonant following a vowel.

Comment: @markE yeah, good point. if i get time, I might play around with that.

Comment: I try your function but the display was blank is any thing wrong with the parameter passing: game.wrapText(fcontent[i], maxWidths, game.context,  true); ? Hint: fcontent-is the text to be wrap into lines, maxWidths is the canvas width, game.context is the context for canvas. Thanks.

Comment: @user2896649 can you do a fiddle showing me how you're using it? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: please bear with me I am a complete novice to js and jquery. this is how I used it: game.context.strokeRect(1,  25, 637, 385);
      game.context.fillStyle = 'brown';
      game.context.font = 'bold 20px sans-serif';
      game.context.textBaseline = 'bottom';
      ctx=game.context;
      var texts=fcontent[i];
      maxWidths=620;
      var textLines = game.wrapWord(texts, maxWidths, ctx, true);
      for (var i = 0, l = textLines.length; i < l; i++) {
    context.fillText(textLines[i], 0, 20 * (i + 1)); }

Comment: @user2896649 man, if you want me to help you, you've gotta help me. put all that in a jsfiddle (use mine to get you started) together with the MINIMUM amount of code to get it to a point where you think it should work.

Comment: @user2896649 here: http://jsfiddle.net/cP5Fz/1/ I've taken your code, commented out the lines that were wrong, explained why, and put in corrected versions. You should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: I am still perplex because the corrected version did not work properly for me because it works only for one element of the array. The remaining elements of the array are not shown. Let me fiddle the whole code for you to see. Thanks.

Comment: A lot of thanks. Indeed U set the path for me. Many thanks once more.

Comment: @BYossarian many thanks once more. However, after implementing this function I can't view the page with Safari but other browsers do including IE. do you have anything to say? Thanks.

Comment: @user2896649 the jsfiddle example i included in the comments works on safari for me. good luck with it.