# How to add /n (new line) to string based on pixel width and limit characters based on pixel height

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, python-imaging-library

What I want to do is add a new line (/n) in a string when it overflows a given pixel width in Javascript.

The text is fetched from a textarea in HTML and will be different based on chosen font and font size. The final string is going to be used with PIL.

I also want to limit input length, and be able to give feedback to the user how much space is left for characters based on pixel width and height.

Does anybody know of any packages or something else that would be able to provide these functionalities?

Comment: Could you provide some code example?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any code to do this in Javascript as of yet. I have looked at canvas, and will keep looking to see if that can help. What I'm looking for is to see if anybody knows of some JS packages which could work!

Comment: You could use measureText on a canvas element to get the text of the string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText

Similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936112/text-wrap-in-a-canvas-element

Comment: Thanks for the input! I found pixi.js which can measure both width and height of fonts. It uses canvas as well, so I might've been able to use that as well!

Answer (score 0):

I created my own solution. Just to update this post in case anybody else might have use for it. Very very basic as of now. Going to continue on it soon and update more hopefully.

It uses [pixi.js](https://www.pixijs.com/) to fetch font metrics. From there it calculates the text written into the textarea and calculates the percentage of how much space is used based on the available pixel area. Just a quick draft as of now. But might help someone else!

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<p id="used-percentage"></p>
<div>
    <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
    <button id="button">Click me</button>

    <p id="string"></p>
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.1.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```html
document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("keypress", readText)

function readText(){
    let string = document.getElementById("editor").value;
    textMetrics(string)
}

function textMetrics(text){
    let style = new PIXI.TextStyle({fontFamily : 'Comic Sans MS', fontSize: 24, wordWrap: true, wordWrapWidth: 640})
    let textMetrics = PIXI.TextMetrics.measureText(text, style)
    console.log(textMetrics)

    // calculatePercentageUsed(textMetrics.maxLineWidth, textMetrics.height)

    calculatePixelUsed(textMetrics.lineWidths, textMetrics.lineHeight)
}

function calculatePixelUsed(lineWidths, lineHeight){
    let squaredLines = [];
    let squarepxUsed = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < lineWidths.length; i++) {
        squaredLines[i] = lineWidths[i] * lineHeight;
        // console.log(squaredLines)
    }

    for (let j = 0; j < squaredLines.length; j++) {
        squarepxUsed += squaredLines[j];
        // console.log(squaredLines)
    }


    calculatePercentage(squarepxUsed)
}

function calculatePercentage(squarepxUsed) {
    let squarepxAvailable = 640 * 384
    let percentage = squarepxUsed / squarepxAvailable * 100
    document.getElementById("used-percentage").innerHTML = percentage
    // console.log(percentage)
}
```

CSS:

```html
#editor {
width: 640px;
height: 384px;
font-family: "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
}
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/noodlesnort/pen/KKdgBQV