# Textarea X/Y caret coordinates - jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, caret

I'm looking to get the X/Y coordinates of the caret within a textarea on key down.  I've searched vigorously but without any luck whatsoever, it seems you can get the position, but not the on-screen X/Y coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

The only viable way of doing this, AFAIK:

1. Append the contents of the TEXTAREA to a DIV
2. Append the DIV to the DOM
3. Place a SPAN inside the DIV at the [character offset of the caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea).
4. Take the offset of the SPAN (`$(span).offset()`...) and minus the offset of the DIV (depending on whether you want the x/y coords relative to the textarea or the page)

Note: When copying the text from the TEXTAREA to the DIV, make sure to copy relevant CSS properties that may affect the offset (width, height, padding, margin, border, font-size, line-height etc.).

Comment: That's the general algorithm, but there are various nuances when it comes to [browser compatibility](https://github.com/component/textarea-caret-position/issues/10#issuecomment-37786158). The **Component.io** team has put together a simple [plugin that works around all edge cases, and doesn't require jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22446703/1269037).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [this](https://github.com/Codecademy/textarea-helper) jQuery plugin for exactly that.

Comment: Great work. Simple to use. Cannot complain about it :)

Comment: @WoIIe: I have a small complaint: if there's a scrollbar, the position may be off by one line. Also, the [caret position can be determined more simply, and without needing jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22446703/1269037).

Comment: Hi, next problem is with auto wrapped long text.