# Show toolbar under selected text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, text, toolbar

I’m trying to show a toolbar under some selected text once the user has selected some text. I browsed through many stackoverflow answers and the best I could come up with is the code below.

I want the toolbar to trigger when a user selects some text not only on **mouse click** but also on **keyboard selection** *(alt+shift+arrow keys)*. Pretty much like in [this text editor](http://hallojs.org).

The `getSelected()` function returns selected text just fine on either mouse or keyboard selection. But when I go to insert a dummy element at that range, it always inserts *(I added some text, "bar", to see where the dummy is inserted)* the dummy at the top of the textarea.

I’m guessing it’s got something to do with `.getRangeAt(0)`. I want to get the position of the selected text (with the insertion of the dummy `<span>`).

```
function getSelected(){
  var t = '';
  if(window.getSelection){
    t = window.getSelection();
  }else if(document.getSelection){
    t = document.getSelection();
  }else if(document.selection){
    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return t;//.toString()
}

$('#post_content').on('select',function(){
    var range = getSelected().getRangeAt(0);
    range.collapse(false);
    var dummy = document.createElement("span");
    // dummy.innerHTML = "bar";
    range.insertNode(dummy);
    var rect = dummy.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = rect.left, y = rect.top;
    dummy.parentNode.removeChild(dummy);
    alert(x + "/" + y);
});
```

Check out the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aTq5q/

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, in jQuery 1.9 the .live() method has been removed.  You should use the .on() method instead to future-proof this: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed

Comment: Thanks, @matt. Changed my code.

Comment: Is the element with ID "post_content" a `<textarea>`?

Comment: @TimDown Yeah, I tried both `<textarea>` and `div contenteditable='true'` but for the `on('select',function(){})` to work it needs to be a `<textarea>`.

**Edit:** Added JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aTq5q/

Comment: That's one reason why I asked :) Another is that in some browsers (Firefox, for example), `window.getSelection()` does not apply to textareas. Another problem is that you won't be able use the insert-a-dummy-node trick within the content of a textarea, since a textarea may only contain text.

Comment: There are similar questions on SO with answers of varying quality. A quick search got me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012835/find-caret-position-in-textarea-in-pixels and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128342/display-div-at-cursor-position-in-textarea and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510009/textarea-caret-coordinates-jquery

Comment: @TimDown Thanks. Yeah, I thought that might be the case. I mean it works fine for the `div` and if I change the script to `$('#post_content').click(function(){` but I also want to trigger it with the keyboard selection. I tried a go at the http://hallojs.org source code, but it’s too complex for my level, to get anything out of it :) Will take a look at those links you gave me.

Comment: If you use contenteditable instead then you can use the (non-standard) `selectionchange` event on the document. Only works in WebKit and IE, sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have two problems:

1. [Determining the X/Y coordinates of the caret in a text area](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22446703/1269037)
2. Catching the selection change event.

For the first problem, check out the [Component.io textarea-caret-position plugin](https://github.com/component/textarea-caret-position/). Small, simple, cross-browser, and doesn't have any dependencies - **[demo](http://is.gd/Po7reS)**.