# Get position top from cursor in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the position Y of the cursor within the textarea. If i type in the textarea and cursor in the middle of the textarea and I try to find the cursors height from the textarea outter width. But I couldn't find that.

I tried `window.getSelection` and `event.pageY`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jdx3f/)

Comment: It's generally tricky. `window.getSelection()` won't help in most browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3510430/96100

Comment: Here's a demo I made a while back for similar question: http://jsfiddle.net/g7rBk/ and the question itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212871/