# Absolute position of character in textarea

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to get absolute position of character in a textarea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's much more complicated than it should be.

There is a [demo](http://enobrev.info/cursor/) demonstrating exactly this functionality, and the method used is discussed in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128342/display-div-at-cursor-position-in-textarea).

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically yes, it is possible, you need to simulate browser's text rendering! But that would be so complicated that I would never even start thinking about it :)