# How can I have a draft.js editor show placeholder text after the cursor?

Tags: draftjs

I have a simple draftjs editor (`megadraft` if it matters). I want to set it up so that my content is displayed and after the cursor, I have placeholder text (grayed out). How would I do this?

Comment: Depending on your use case you could generate a virtual element  with getVisibleSelectionRect from draft.js and use it as reference Other option would be to show a div at cursor position: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128342/display-div-at-cursor-position-in-textarea/163395