# jQuery get textarea cursor/caret X,Y position and show a DIV underneath

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, caret

I am trying to implement something like the "Change/Remove Link" in Gmail/Google Docs richtext WYSIWYG edtior, when you type a URL, a div shows underneath it says "Goto Link, Change, Remote"

How could I write something like that using jQuery?

1. How to get row and column of cursor?
2. how can I calculate font width and height (especially non-fixed width font with some Bold/Italic style)
3. How to make sure the DIV appears at the start of a word?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: looking at google results, most of which didn't help very much.

Comment: You're suggesting you're building a WYSIWYG editor. Are you sure you want to use a `textarea`? Textareas don't support HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the (x, y) pixel coordinates of the caret in text boxes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709/how-do-i-get-the-x-y-pixel-coordinates-of-the-caret-in-text-boxes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer: http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/57BR3/**

**What it does:**

- Creates div positioned near hyperlink.
- Looks like Google docs box.
- Ability to change text and url.
- Remove is implemented.

**What it does not do:**

- Work on textarea.  Textareas don't support html as they are plain text. This is a complex process to work-around.  Find a library, then implement my answer.
- Open when your cursor gets moved onto it by arrowkeys.  Doesn't work because of above item.

Comment: @Levi works great but is there any particular reason using $body.delegate('#main a', 'click', function(e) { ....... instead of using simple $('#main a').click()?

Comment: Yes, actually.  Your way creates multiple event handlers.  My way has one.  Additionally, when you click off of the element, you want it to go away.  I accidentally removed that piece of code from the fiddle, but it's back in now.  If you bind on #main the click doesn't work properly.  Try changing the $body.delegate to $('#main') and it will fail.  Never did figure out why.  If you can solve this, please clue me in on the solution.

Comment: @Levi Morrison Thanks a lot man, I can learn a lot from your code. But do you know any way to calculate cursor position? My question was intend to make something like autocomplete/autosuggest dropdown menus in VisualStudio/Eclipse, thus I have to get the whole "word" before the cursor, in both IE and other browsers. For example I type `window.` in a textarea, the cursor stays after the `.`, but I need to grab the nearest text before the cursor: `window`, with some AJAX calls I can display a div right under the word `window` and user can choose something from list of items.

Comment: @est I'm not sure I fully understand what you are saying, but to get the position of an event you can use e.pageX and e.pageY

Comment: @est This would create a lot of DOM elements, but if every word was wrapped in a span tag, you could use a delegate on it's parent and do $parent.delegate('span', 'click', funciton(e){});  That's the best answer I can come up with at the moment.

Comment: Updated jsfiddle.  I removed an unnecessary if statement inside of delegate.  It was left-over from a previous method of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're suggesting you're building a WYSIWYG editor. Are you sure you want to use a textarea? Textareas don't support HTML. To answer your [later comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752147/jquery-get-textarea-cursor-caret-x-y-position-and-show-a-div-underneath?rq=1#comment6587561_5753757), the best way to get the (x, y) position of the caret in a text area is to use the [textarea-caret-position plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22446703/1269037).