# Caret position in textarea in IE using jQuery caret plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this [plguin](http://www.jquery-plugin.buss.hk/my-plugins/jquery-caret-plugin) to get caret position of textarea. I have a `<div>`, clicking on which shows the `<ul>`with smilie list to put one of them into the textarea. Clicking on `<div>` fires the `blur` event on textarea. I save the caret position on blur:

```
oRoot.blur(function() {
    caret_pos = $(this).caret();
});
```

And after user click on smilie, I put it in the textarea where the caret was before it lost the focus:

```
oList
    .delegate('.chat-smile', 'click', function() {
        var oRoot = $(this).parent().data('oRoot');

        if (is_default_value(oRoot)) oRoot.val('');

        oRoot.val(oRoot.caret(caret_pos).caret().replace($(this).attr('smilie-code')));

        toggle_list($(this).parent());
    });
```

The problem is that in IE it seems that the plugin doesn't work if textarea has no focus, and in IE the `blur` event handler is fired after the focus is lost.

Any ideas of workaround this? I was thinking of saving the caret position on `click`, `keyup`, `focus` for IE..

Comment: Related: [How do I get the (x, y) pixel coordinates of the caret in text boxes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709/how-do-i-get-the-x-y-pixel-coordinates-of-the-caret-in-text-boxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the workaround I thought of befor (saving the caret position on click, keyup, focus for IE).
So now function which binds events to save caret position looks like this:

```
function bind_save_caret_pos() {
    var event_to_bind = $.browser.msie ? 'keyup mouseup' : 'blur';

    oRoot.bind(event_to_bind, function() {
        caret_pos = $(this).caret();
    });
}
```

`keyup` deals with typing, deleting, moving around the text with arrows etc.

`mouseup` deals with selecting peace of text, moving cursor etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://i.guibench.com/snippet/ag9zfmd1aWJlbmNoYWxwaGFyDwsSB1Byb2plY3QYgfcCDA) is another way to get the caret position in IE. You can use it , if you like.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for response! But selectionStart is not supported by IE < 9, and the plugin I'm using considers this fact. The problem is using the BLUR event. Keypress is fine, because textarea has the focus when typing.