# How to find pageX-pageY positions of the cursor (when inside a textbox) using javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor-position

I need to find the pageX and pageY positions of the cursor within a textbox on any event, such as keyup.

```
<input type="text" id="addOwner">

$("#addOwner").keyup(function(event) {
    var pageY = event.pageY;  // currently getting Undefined
    var pageX = event.pageX;  // currently getting undefined  
})
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishkumarshr/YfB5v/).

Comment: `keyup` event doesn't have `pageX` or `pageY`

Comment: yes, then how to find the positions? that's my question

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-the-caret-in-text-boxes

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Check jQuery `offset()` to find out the text box  position. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YfB5v/1/)

```
$("#addOwner").keyup(function(event) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var pageY = offset.left;  // currently getting Undefined
    var pageX = offset.top;  // currently getting undefined 
    alert(pageY);
    alert(pageX);
})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-within-an-text-input-field

Comment: That doesn't work. It alerts "10" all the time.

Comment: doesnt work!!!!!