# How can I change input blink caret style with easy css, js

Tags: css, caret, input-field

I wonder how can I use css/javascript to adjust the blinking cursor inside the search box with CSS?

[image]

Is it possible to replace default blinkig caret  to horizontal blinking icon

Comment: **No**. Many have tried and failed before you (including me). If you really want to pursue it (good luck), you'll need to a textbox with invisible text, a `div` underneath it which then updates to contain the text, and then another `div` styled the way you want the caret to look which moves as the user types and selects. Although, I think WebKit browsers can do it natively...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling text input caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret)

Comment: There is a CSS property to do that, but not supported yet: [`caret-shape`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-4/#caret-shape).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is so hard. I made a quick example, which works in most modern browsers except Safari.
It draws the caret on a canvas, and sets it as a background of the input, on a position calculated from the browsers caret position.

It checks if the browser supports the `caret-color` css property, and if it doesn't it doesn't do anything, because both the system caret, and our caret will be visible in the same time. From the browsers I tested, only Safari doesn't support it.

```js
$("input").on('change blur mouseup focus keydown keyup', function(evt) {
  var $el = $(evt.target);
  //check if the carret can be hidden
  //AFAIK from the modern mainstream browsers
  //only Safari doesn't support caret-color
  if (!$el.css("caret-color")) return;
  var caretIndex = $el[0].selectionStart;
  var textBeforeCarret = $el.val().substring(0, caretIndex);

  var bgr = getBackgroundStyle($el, textBeforeCarret);
  $el.css("background", bgr);
  clearInterval(window.blinkInterval);
  //just an examplethis should be in a module scope, not on window level
  window.blinkInterval = setInterval(blink, 600);
})

function blink() {
 
  $("input").each((index, el) => {
    var $el = $(el);
    if ($el.css("background-blend-mode") != "normal") {
      $el.css("background-blend-mode", "normal");
    } else {
      $el.css("background-blend-mode", "color-burn");
    }
  });
}


function getBackgroundStyle($el, text) {
  var fontSize = $el.css("font-size");
  var fontFamily = $el.css("font-family");

  var font = fontSize + " " + fontFamily;
  var canvas = $el.data("carretCanvas");
  //cache the canvas for performance reasons
  //it is a good idea to invalidate if the input size changes because of the browser text resize/zoom)
  if (canvas == null) {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    $el.data("carretCanvas", canvas);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = font;
    ctx.strokeStyle = $el.css("color");
    ctx.lineWidth = Math.ceil(parseInt(fontSize) / 5);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    //aproximate width of the caret
    ctx.lineTo(parseInt(fontSize) / 2, 0);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  var offsetLeft = canvas.getContext("2d").measureText(text).width + parseInt($el.css("padding-left"));
  return "#fff url(" + canvas.toDataURL() + ") no-repeat " +
    (offsetLeft - $el.scrollLeft()) + "px " +
    ($el.height() + parseInt($el.css("padding-top"))) + "px";
}
```

```css
input {
  caret-color: transparent;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #2795EE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

If there is interest, I can clean it a bit and wrap it in a jQuery plugin.

Edit: forgot about the blinking, so I added it. A better way will be to add it as css animation, in this case the caret should be in a separate html element positioned over the input.

Comment: Quite awesome solution ;)

Comment: Thanks for the solution basically i was making this for Telephone Text Fields Thanks again :-) cheers

Comment: The caret doesn't move as fast as the text is deleted or added, but the effect is here.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the color of the caret is supported by the latest standards. But not changing its width is not, which I think is a shame because it is a question of accessibility for vision-impaired people.

One approach for implementing such a change yourself is first trying to figure out what is the position the caret is blinking at, then overlaying it with an element that looks like the caret but is perhaps wider etc.

Here's an article on how to go about doing such a thing. It's a good article but the end-solution is kind of complicated as a whole. But see if it solves your problem:

https://medium.com/@jh3y/how-to-where-s-the-caret-getting-the-xy-position-of-the-caret-a24ba372990a

Here is perhaps a simpler explanation for how to find the care x-y position: 
[How do I get the (x, y) pixel coordinates of the caret in text boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709/how-do-i-get-the-x-y-pixel-coordinates-of-the-caret-in-text-boxes)